# Is Stack Overflow making programmers lazy?

Tags: discussion

Come on; I mean Stack Overflow is great, but programmers should help themselves by doing their best.

Most of askers just want a ready made answer. I experienced it. What do you think?

Comment: Why should we care? As long as we are building *good questions* and *good answers* to those questions, we are helping all the other lazy programmers out there just looking for an answer. And that happens to be the goal of Stack Overflow!

Comment: Programmers are lazy, they spend hours to write a program to automate a 5 minute job.

Comment: Or are you talking about a lack of effort on behalf of the question asker? Perhaps you should read [Should Stack Overflow be awarding "A"s for Effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840) in that case.

Comment: SO *is* enabling lazy behaviour among programmers. It's easy to not take part in that, though, by simply not answering lazy questions, and downvoting/closevoting them where appropriate.

Comment: There's a difference between being lazy - to find an efficient approach and take weeks on to only ever have to do once or twice from then on, and being slothful (asking someone to write your code).  Slothful programmers often weed themselves out; even if they're spoon fed, they won't be able to keep up with what's demanded of them.

Comment: @Makoto ,you are correct , i saw 1 question in Java section had -45 downvotes "Why is false!=false Returns false ?" .Such lazy users should not be tolerated.

Comment: No...wait...that doesn't sound like laziness.  That sounds like confusion.  Heck, *I* don't even know why that's the case.  That sounds like a genuine question.

Comment: @Makoto always false==false ?? it results true so its opposite will result to False.

Comment: Is this just a rant (whose conclusion is unclear to me) or are you trying to have a serious discussion? Maybe you could clarify what your point is

Comment: @Pekka웃 ,its not serious discussion

Comment: *sigh* why waste people's time then? Let me convert my upvote into a downvote....

Comment: @Pekka웃 you edited the answer to downvote me on purpose :( .This is really bad.

Comment: All of that could have been prevented by avoiding calling people Nazis and by not stating you're not serious about this discussion to begin with.

Comment: Well...the example you've provided `false == false` actually returns `false`.  This is confusing and I'm not sure why you'd call a programmer "lazy" for not understanding this right out of the gate.

Comment: @Makoto Sure, slothful programmers often (eventually) weed themselves out, but the problem is that there's a constant supply of them and there are too many tolerators on [so] (and the general mindset that we should comment and wait for ... ever before downvoting or closing is also a problem).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't share that mindset.  If the question is genuinely bad, why hesitate to act on its quality?

Comment: @Makoto I agree, but I see too many who don't (although I'm not really talking about the truly terrible, but rather those that get quite a few comments pointing out problems serious enough to warrant closure and downvoting, yet no closure and downvoting happens).

Comment: WHY THIS QUESTION IS STILL THERE, DELETE THIS PLEASE!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A big NO to your concern because Stack Overflow motivate users to try before asking the question. Stack Overflow only welcome the question where user have something already tried but he stuck and really need help of experts.

If you see such kind of post where OP is asking for code its usually get downvoted or closed. Yes, some question get posted and also get answered but it is not recommended by the community.